# Loop through agents Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent, agent-based-modeling

I want to link every agent from breed 1 to ONE other agent from breed 2.

```
create-breed1 20 [
 let breed2-number random 20
 create-link-with breed2 breed2-number
]
```

The problem is now that every agent from breed 1 is connected to one agent of breed 2 but breed 2 is sometimes linked to more than one agent of breed 1 and sometimes not linked at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the breed2 turtles to remove those that already have a link before selecting turtles to create links with. You probably want something like:

```
breed [breeds1 breed1]
breed [breeds2 breed2]

ask breeds1
[ create-link-with one-of (breeds2 with [not any? link-neighbors])
]
```

I am assuming you have more breeds2 turtles than breeds1 turtles so there is a turtle available to link to.

Comment: I have the same amount of breed1 and breed2.
I tried your solution but then I get an error message: BREED2 expected 1 input, a number
The problem is that one-of adresses an agentset and not a single agent

Comment: breed1 and breed2 are defined as breed. I defined the breeds at the beginning of the code as
breed [breeds1 breed1]
breed [breeds2 breed2]
sorry I didn't add it

Comment: that's the problem - you need breeds2, not breed2 in my code (I had thought breed2 was plural)